# Simple UI in Wordpress required to insert / update mysql table rows

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, insert-update

I want to update or insert mysql table records from within the wordpress. Basically a form is required for the same. Request anyone to guide how I can do that.

Although I know I can do the same phpmyadmin but I don't want to do that as I've to open phpmyadmin everytime for the same and its easy to do it from wordpress user console.

Comment: You don't really say what you want to do. What have you tried? did you consider plugins? This is a 'question' with too little information.

Answer (score 1):

as far as i understand, you want to do some DML on some Not-wordpress table in mysql. so, if you are the only one who can open that wordpress, although in this case i suggest you make a theme options page, then use it for SQL, all you need is to include some text area {name="sql_text"} and save button {type="submit" name="danger"}, Then do some thing like:

```
if(isset($_POST['danger'])) {
     $sql_text = $_POST['sql_text'];//dont use double quotation in your code,unless to use some $variables... im serious
     $query = mysql_query($sql_text);
}
```

and in your "sql_text" text area field, you might write something like this:

```
INSERT INTO ".$wpdb->yourTableNameWithoutPrefix." Values('your','')
```

and remember, don't let the colorful looks of the last piece of code deceive you.

Again, like this, your site is vulnerable.

Salam